# Passing functions as arguments 'Trying to understand the link'

Tags: javascript

just learning some javascript...

I have currently coded this:

```
// an array of random years
var years = [1990, 1965, 1937, 1998, 1988];

// function to place all given values into a new array in this case arrRes
function arrayCalc(arr, fn){
  var arrRes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arrRes.push(fn(arr[i]));
  }
  return arrRes;
}


//function to calculate the age
function calcage(el){
  return  2019 - el;
}


var ages = arrayCalc(years, calcage);
console.log(ages);
```

I understand how to code this, because its stuck in my head through repetition.

But, I still cannot figure out what is going on in the background, in terms of the linking between all codes and functions.

Mainly the last part is what im more confused about, I don't understand the link between `el` with the rest of the code and how does it return the values as they do currently?... could someone explain in more depth please?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `arrayCalc(years, calcage)`, the variable `arr` will be set to `years`, and `fn` will be set to `calcage`.

In the loop, you call `fn(arr[i])`. Because of the above parameter assignments, this is equivalent to `calcage(years[i])`.

Inside `calcage`, `el` is set to `years[i]`, it subtracts it from `2019`, and returns this. The result is then pushed onto `arrRes` in `arrayCalc`.

BTW, your `arrayCalc` function is equivalent to the built-in `map` method of arrays. `arrayCalc(years, calcage)` can be written as `years.map(calcage)`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your amazing response, very clear! also.. still little confused on the `el`.... correct me if I am wrong. So the `el` is changed to `years` because inside the `arrayCalc(years, calcage)` `years` is on the left and inserted into `el`? So if it was like this as an example: `arrayCalc(dateOfBirth, calcage)` now `el` would be set as `dateOfBirth`?

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand the basics of function calling. `el` is whatever the argument to `calcage` is. If you call `calcage(arr[i])` then it's whatever the value of `arr[i]` is. Since `arr` is `years`, `arr[i]` is `years[i]`. So `el` is `years[i]`.

Comment: If you do `arrayCalc(dateOfBirth, calcage)`, `el` will be `dateOfBirth[i]`.

Comment: I'm on the right lines then? yeah forgot the `[i]` apologizes

Answer (score 0):

Starting at the end:

```
var ages = arrayCalc(years, calcage);
```

years is an array, and calcage is a function, both of which get passed to the arrayCalc function.  (Note that the param is "calcage", not "calcage()" -- without the parens it passes the function itself to arrayCalc; with the parens it would instead call the calcage function and pass its *output* to arrayCalc.)

Now skipping back to arrayCalc itself:

```
function arrayCalc(arr, fn){
```

Inside arrayCalc, arr is the array passed in as "years", and fn is the function passed in as "calcage".  So within arrayCalc, calling `fn()` would be the same thing as calling `calcage()` directly.

So when arrayCalc calls `fn(arr[i])`, it ends up passing the contents of arr[i] on to calcage():

```
function calcage(el){
```

which names that value "el", does some math, and returns the result (back to arrayCalc, which pushes it onto the array that it will eventually return into `ages`.)

(It's probably worth pointing out that, given only this code, there's no practical reason to pass calcage as a function parameter instead of just calling it directly.  This sort of thing becomes useful when you have multiple different functions you might pass into arrayCalc; then it can be a general-purpose "do whatever arbitrary task you pass into me to each element in this array" instead of "do this specific thing to each element in this array".)

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraph. `arrayCalc()` is a general purpose function, it can be used to call any function on the array elements.

Comment: Yes, I was just trying to explain that  since there *aren't* any other functions currently, it'd be more straightforward to call calcage() directly; but you're probably right that I'm confusing the issue more than clarifying it. I'll rewrite.